# Duplicating values because of SQL string?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ado.net

I made my own SQL string that uses INNER JOINS. Here is my function:

```
string cmdstr = @"SELECT s.*, mdb.menu_name
                  FROM stocksdb s, recipelist rl
                  INNER JOIN menudb mdb  ON rl.menu_ID = mdb.menu_ID
                  WHERE rl.stock_ID = '" + stockID + "'";

var cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, db.mycon);
var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    var menuname = dr["menu_name"].ToString();

    stockIDTxtbox.Text = stockID;
    nameTxtBox.Text = dr["stock_name"].ToString();
    availableTxtbox.Text = dr["stock_quantity"].ToString();
    pricePerPieceTxtbox.Text = dr["stock_pricePerPiece"].ToString();
    limitTxtBox.Text = dr["stock_limit"].ToString());

    recipeList.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { menuname });
}
```

Now the problem is, when I click one Item on the `stocksList ListView` the `recipeList ListView` would have multiple values. Like 5 or so rows of the same values.

Comment: Please also correct me for problems with my SQL syntax

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A join with stocksdb is missing. Something like this:

```
   SELECT s.*, mdb.menu_name 
   FROM stocksdb s

   INNRER JOIN recipelist rl 
   ON s.stock_ID= r1.stock_ID   <== this join was missing

   INNER JOIN menudb mdb 
   ON rl.menu_ID = mdb.menu_ID 
   WHERE rl.stock_ID = '" + stockID
```